# Unable to view message tray in Gnome 3.6

Tags: gnome, notification-area

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my new laptop and switched to Gnome shell session. It seems that the notification tray doesn't appear at the bottom of the screen.

Some details about what works:

- in the activities overview, the message tray is present and works as expected
- the new messages appear at the bottom middle of the screen, as they should
- I can interact with these messages normally, as long as they are displayed

So what I am just missing is the big bar with the icons that should appear when I place my mouse at the bottom of the screen.

This problem has been there since the install, meaning without any extension.

Is there something to do to get it work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried pushing the mouse hard against the bottom of the screen? I usually have a hard time trying to make it appear.

Comment: OK I found it: I need to keep the mouse at the bottom of the screen for 2 seconds before it appears.